# Parse.com:How to find error details of Push?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I migrated my app to a new developer account. As per Apple guidelines I regenerated the ssl certificate for push notification.

I converted the SSL certificate and uploaded to parse. However from then on parse is showing Done(with error) for status of any push notification. How to find the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the error, it will take you to a new page with more info, is there an error message there?

Click here:
[image]

To get to detailed view, something like this:

[image]

I'm guessing that's where the error message would be.  Let me know if it's not and I'll remove this as an answer.